# Leaflet custom icon resize on zoom. Performance icon vs divicon

Tags: jquery, css, leaflet, marker

I was trying to resize my custom icons when zooming in leaflet. I came up with two solutions for this. One using the `L.Icon` tag, the other one using `L.divIcon`. In both examples I only set 1 marker and group for readability

**Method 1** using **L.Icon**: make groups with markers. Then on `zoomend` i use `mygroup.eachLayer(function (layer)` to change all icons for 1 layer using `layer.setIcon()`. I repeat this for all groups

```
<script>
// Setting map options
....

// Setting Icon
var normalicon = L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'icon1.jpg',
    iconSize:     [40,40],
    iconAnchor:   [20,20],
    popupAnchor:  [0,-20] 
    });


// Create a group
var normalLayer = L.layerGroup([
    L.marker([200,200], {icon:normalicon})
]).addTo(map);

// Resizing on zoom
map.on('zoomend', function() {

    // Normal icons
    var normaliconresized = L.Icon.extend({
        options: {
            iconSize: [20*(map.getZoom()+2), 20*(map.getZoom()+2)], // New size!
            iconAnchor:   [20,20],
            popupAnchor:  [0,-20]
        }
    });

    var normaliconchange = new normaliconresized({iconUrl: 'icon1.jpg'})
    normalLayer.eachLayer(function (layer) {
        layer.setIcon(normaliconchange);
    });

    .... Do the same for the other groups
});             
</script>
```

**Method 2** using **L.divIcon**: I make the icons and the different groups and add some CSS for each icon with a `background-image` property. Then on `zoomend` I simply use JQuery to change the css. `background-size` css-property allows me to change the image size. I do this for each divIcon class I have

```
Css
.iconsdiv{
    width:20px; height:20px;
    background-image:url("icon2.jpg");
    background-size: 20px 20px;
}


Script
<script>
// Setting map options
....


// Setting Icon

var divicon = L.divIcon({className: 'iconsdiv', iconSize: null }); // Explicitly set to null or you will default to 12x12


// Create a group
var divLayer = L.layerGroup([
    L.marker([200,200], {icon:divicon})
]).addTo(map);


// Resizing on zoom
map.on('zoomend', function() {

    var newzoom = '' + (20*(map.getZoom()+2)) +'px';
    $('#map .iconsdiv').css({'width':newzoom,'height':newzoom,'background-size':newzoom + ' ' + newzoom}); 

     ... repeat for the other classes
});


</script>
```

I have barely any experience with javascript/jquery/...

Is the second option preferable as it does not require re-setting each icon? Would it improve performance when there is a large number of groups/icons?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I did a test myself using `performance.now()`. I tested on a 1024x1180 (bounds) custom map. Once with 676 makers. Then with about half of this and lastly with 100 markers. The performance was measured inside the `map.on('zoomend', function() {` function.

- For 676 markers it took 2500-2900 milliseconds for the `L.Icon`method to update. For the `L.divIcon`this was only 10-30 milliseconds.
- Half the amount of markers also halved this time.
- For about 100 markers (104) `L.Icon` took 300-400 milliseconds to update. `L.divIcon` did the same in only 4-5 milliseconds.

I also timed the performance of the initialization (`L.layerGroup([...]).addTo(map)`) for 676 markers. `L.Icon` took 2200-2400 milliseconds. `L.divIcon` did the same in 80-95 milliseconds.

`L.divIcon` clearly does a lot better (as expected). While it is a bit of a cheat, I guess I would prefer using this method. I can not directly think of reasons why the `L.Icon`method would be preferred in case we want zooming

Edit:
I noticed that according to [Leaflet Documentation 'Icon'](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.2.0.html#icon) you can also assign a className to the Icons. Using css-properties `width` and `height` the same can be done as I did earlier for the divIcons, thus saving you a lot of loading time, yet allowing you to use all options linked to `L.Icon`. Your initialisation time will still be longer though.